# Sequential search does not work as expected

Tags: java, arraylist

I have written a program which takes the words the user have entered, with a button press, and puts them in an ArrayList. There is also another text field where the user can enter a letter or word, for which the user can search for in the ArrayList with another button press. I'm using a sequential search algorithm to accomplish this, but it does not work as I expect it to; If the searched word is found, the search function should return, and print out in a textArea that the word was found and where in the array it was found. This works, but only for the first search. If the word is not found, the function should print out that the word was not found. This works as I want it to.

The problem is that after I searched for one word, and it displays where in the ArrayList this can be found, nothing happens when I press the button after that, whether the entered letter/word is in the array or not. It's like the string that the text gets stored isn't changing. I don't understand why... Here below is the custom `Class` of the search function and then my `Main` class:

```
public class Search {
    static private int i;
    static String index;
    static boolean found = false;

public static String sequencial (ArrayList<String> list, String user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(user)) {
            index = "The word " + user  + " exist on the place " + i + " in the Arraylist";
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        index = "The word " + user + " could not be found";
    }
    return index;
}
```

My `Main` class:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();   

private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    txtaOutput.setText("");
    String word = txtfAdd.getText();
    list.add(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        txtaOutput.append("" + list.get(i) + "\n");
    }
}

private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String user = txtfSearch.getText();
    txtaOutput.setText("");
    String index = Search.sequencial(list, user);
    txtaOutput.setText("" + index);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use indexOf like the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you declared your `found` variable as `static`. When your first word is found, it is set to `true`, and nothing ever sets it back to false. Instead of making it a static variable, declare it as a local variable inside your `sequencial` (it's spelled *sequential*, by the way) function, just before the for-loop.

In fact, all the variables you've declared as static should be made local. Declaring static variables is **never** a good idea.

Comment: You are right, All the three variables i, index, found should be local. No need to declare it static. Either he can clear it before using it in method. found=false;

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As said by other users:

- There is the `List#indexOf(Object)` method. You should use that instead of reinventing the wheel (unless you need to, and in that case you might have a look at the `ArrayList` implementation). There are also other collections, like `HashSet` which are more apropiate for looking up, but i guess that is another history.
- The scope and the names of the variables (i, index, found) is error-prone. Do other methods or even classes need to have access to those variables? If you need to keep those variables, you might want to choose a visibility (public,protected,private). "index" is a misleading choice of a name for a message.

This would be an slightly simplified/corrected version of your code:

```
// Ommit those unneeded static variables

public static String sequencial (ArrayList<String> list, String user) {
    int indexFound = list.indexOf(user);
    if (user >= 0) {
         return "The word " + user  + " exist on the place " + indexFound + " in the Arraylist";
    } else {
         return "The word " + user + " could not be found";
    }
}
...
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String user = txtfSearch.getText();
    // txtaOutput.setText("");
    String seqMessage = sequencial(list, user);
    txtaOutput.setText(seqMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the static properties when you would like to use the constants. You should not use the static properties here. The problem will happen when your found property is changed the first time, it will not be changed again. And from that time, it will always be true. Similar with index property. Here is the code you can fix this:

```
public class Search {

    public static SearchResult sequencial (ArrayList<String> list, String user) {
        SearchResult result = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(user)) {
                String index = "The word " + user  + " exist on the place " + i + " in the Arraylist";
                boolean found = true;
                result = new SearchResult(index, found);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (result == null) {
            String index = "The word " + user + " could not be found";
            result = new SearchResult(index);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //sample inner class
    static class SearchResult {
        private String index;
        private boolean found;

        public SearchResult(String index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public SearchResult(String index, boolean found) {
            this.index = index;
            this.found = found;
        }

        public String getIndex() {
            return index;
        }
        public void setIndex(String index) {
            this.index = index;
        }
        public boolean isFound() {
            return found;
        }
        public void setFound(boolean found) {
            this.found = found;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: constants are declared as **final** static, which is a very important difference, because that's what makes them constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SequencialSearcher {

    public static int SequencialSearchInt(int[] inputArray, int key)
    {

        for(int i=0; i < inputArray.length ; i++)

        {
            if(inputArray[i] == key)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static int SequencialSearchString(String[] array, String key)
    {

        for(int i=0; i < array.length ; i++)

        {
            if(array[i] == key)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static int SequencialSearchFloat(double[] array, double key)
    {

        for(int i=0; i < array.length ; i++)

        {
            if(array[i] == key)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        //select the type of the elements of search
        //1 if integers
        //2 if float
        //3 if string
        int x = 3;
        int[] array1 = {9, 0, 10, 8, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3};
        double[] array2 = {9.0, 0.0, 10.0, 8.0, 5.0, 4.0, 6.0, 2.0, 3.0};
        String[] array3 = {"aa","hey", "hello"};
        if(x == 1){
            //enter the integer you want to search for here below
            int requiredValue = 5;
            int result = SequencialSearchInt(array1, requiredValue);
            if (result != -1)
                {
                System.out.println("Required Value: "+requiredValue+" found at index: "+result);
                }
            else
                {
                System.out.println("Value:"+requiredValue+" not found");
                }
        }
        else if(x == 2)
        {
            //enter the double you want to search for here below
            double requiredValue1 = 5.0;
            int result = SequencialSearchFloat(array2, requiredValue1);
            if (result != -1)
                {
                System.out.println("Required Value: "+requiredValue1+" found at index: "+result);
                }
            else
                {
                System.out.println("Value:"+requiredValue1+" not found");
                }
        }
        else if(x == 3){
            //enter the string you want to search for here below
            String requiredValue2 = "hey";
            int result = SequencialSearchString(array3, requiredValue2);
            if (result != -1)
                {
                System.out.println("Required Value: "+requiredValue2+" found at index: "+result);
                }
            else
                {
                System.out.println("Value:"+requiredValue2+" not found");
                }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error. Please select 1,2 and 3 only");
        }
    }
}
```